# What's the best monitoring framework and tool like Nagios in the MS Windows Environment?

Tags: windows, nagios

I know Nagios that runs in the UNIX Envirionment.
But I can't find one that runs in MS Windows.
I prefer freeware or Open Source. But I don't care commercial production.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, you may find that much of it is already present in the Windows environment. What do you need, and which Windows versions do you need it on?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems

There are many tools like:

ZYRION
SOLARWINDS
NIMSOFT
ZABBIX